# How to reduce Sun/Oracle JVM internal overhead?

Tags: java, eclipse, memory, jvm, overhead

This problem is specifically about **Sun Java JVM running on Linux x86-64**. I'm trying to figure out **why the Sun JVM takes so much of system's physical memory even when I have set Heap and Non-Heap limits**.

The program I'm running is Eclipse 3.7 with multiple plugins/features. The most used features are PDT, EGit and Mylyn. I'm starting the Eclipse with the following command line switches:

```
-nosplash -vmargs -Xincgc -Xms64m -Xmx200m -XX:NewSize=8m -XX:PermSize=80m -XX:MaxPermSize=150m -XX:MaxPermHeapExpansion=10m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin=0 -XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycle=5 -XX:GCTimeRatio=49 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=1000 -XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+AggressiveOpts -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.disablePrinting
```

Worth noting are especially the switches:

```
-Xms64m -Xmx200m -XX:NewSize=8m -XX:PermSize=80m -XX:MaxPermSize=150m
```

These switches **should limit the JVM Heap to maximum of 200 MB and Non-Heap to 150 MB** ("CMS Permanent generation" and "Code Cache" as labeled by JConsole). Logically the JVM should take total of 350 MB plus the internal overhead required by the JVM.

**In reality, the JVM takes 544.6 MB** for my current Eclipse process as computed by ps_mem.py (http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ps_mem.py) which computes the real physical memory pages reserved by the Linux 2.6+ kernel. **That's internal Sun JVM overhead of 35% or roughly 200MB!**

**Any hints about how to decrease this overhead?**

Here's some additional info:

```
$ ps auxw
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
me       23440  2.4 14.4 1394144 558440 ?      Sl   Oct12 210:41 /usr/bin/java ...
```

And according to JConsole, the process has used 160 MB of heap and 151 MB of non-heap.

I'm not saying that I cannot afford using extra 200MB for running Eclipse, but if there's a way to reduce this waste, I'd rather use that 200MB for kernel block device buffers or file cache. In addition, I have similar experience with other Java programs -- perhaps I could reduce the overhead for all of them with similar tweaks.

Update: After posting the question, I found previous post to SO:
[Why does the Sun JVM continue to consume ever more RSS memory even when the heap, etc sizes are stable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612939/why-does-the-sun-jvm-continue-to-consume-ever-more-rss-memory-even-when-the-heap)
It seems that I should use `pmap` to investigate the problem.

Comment: Are you *really* using a Sun JVM? Or are you using a current Oracle JVM?

Comment: Here is a bit of what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561245/virtual-memory-usage-from-java-under-linux-too-much-memory-used

Comment: What's the difference between Sun JVM and Oracle JVM? I'm getting following: "$ java -version"
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: @Mikko: Recent versions are actually the Oracle JVM. [Oracle has bought Sun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_acquisition_by_Oracle) some time ago, so sometime around the Java 6u20 release all the "Sun JVMs" start actually being "Oracle JVMs".

Comment: For RSS size growing in Java processes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041117/growing-resident-memory-usage-rss-of-java-process/35610063

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason for the high memory consumption of your Eclipse Environment is the use of SWT. SWT is a native graphic library living outside of the heap of the JVM, and to worsen the situation, the implementation on Linux is not really optimized.

I don't think there's really a chance to reduce the memory consumption of your eclipse environment concerning the memory outside the heap.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is a memory and cpu hog. In addition to the Java class libraries all the low end GUI stuff is handled by native system calls so you will have a substantial "native" JNI library to execute the low level X term calls attached to your process.

Eclipse offers millions of useful features and lots of helpers to speed up your day to day programming tasks - but lean and mean it is not. Any reduction in memory or resources will probably result in a noticeable slowdown. It really depends on how much you value your time vs. your computers memory.

If you want lean and mean gvim and make are unbeatable. If you want the code completion, automatic builds etc. you must expect to pay for this with extra resources.

Comment: I'm not using any "IDE" features of Eclipse (for me "IDE" means automatic code generation, automatic builds, etc). I'm using Eclipse as a really smart text editor with smart ondemand code completion support, code navigation helper and integrated online documentation tool. Add the Mylyn in the stack and the end result is really better than emacs or vim for the features. I agree that "make" is better for automated builds and I also think that "git gui" and "gitk" are superior to EGit/Eclipse support. It's just that it's even better to have Eclipse tools in addition to other tools.

Answer (score 0):

If I run the following program

```
public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        System.out.println("waiting " + i);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

with `ps auwx` prints

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
500      13165  0.0  0.0 596680 13572 pts/2    Sl+  13:54   0:00 java -Xms64m -Xmx200m -XX:NewSize=8m -XX:PermSize=80m -XX:MaxPermSize=150m -cp . Main
```

The amount of memory used is 13.5 MB. There about 200 MB of shared libraries which counts towards the VSZ size. The rest can be acounted for in the max heap, max perm gen with an overhead for the thread stacks etc.

The problem doesn't appear to be with the JVM but the application running in it.  Using additional shared libraries, direct memory and memory mapped files can increase the amount of memory used.

Given you can buy 16 GB for around $100, do you know this is actually a problem?

Comment: Sure, memory is cheap but I'd hate to waste 200 MB of real memory if there were a simple fix. Currently I think that HefferWolf is right and this is caused by SWT. I didn't previously realize that JVM cannot monitor or limit SWT memory usage.

Comment: Its usually a good idea to test a simple configuration for comparision purposes if you are trying to isolate the cause of a problem. ;)

Comment: I prefer to use IntelliJ which doesn't use SWT. (Nor does Netbeans)